# Display data in the html coming from http service in json Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I would like to get some help with this simple trouble.

I got an API which returns me the following message:

```
[
  "{\"name\":\"testing\",\"desc\":\"test\",\"other\":\"search\"}",
  "{\"name\":\"test\",\"des\":\"testing\",\"other\":\"search\"}"
]
```

I am using this model:

```
export class myModel {
    name: string;
    desc?: string;
    other: string;
}
```

I am getting the message properly with the following service:

```
  private emitList$ = new Subject<myModel[]>();
  private listObserver$: Observable<myModel[]> = this.emitList$.asObservable();

  public getting() {
    this.http.get<myModel[]>(this.URI_ENDPOINT_GET_URI, this.httpheaders)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    )
    .subscribe(list=> {
      this.emitList$.next(list);
    });
  }

  public getListObserver(): Observable<myModel[]> {
    return this.listObserver$;
  }
```

This is called from my typescript view code using the following code:

```
  constructor(private myService: MyService,
              private changeDetectorRefs: ChangeDetectorRef ) {
              }

  dataModel: myModel[];
  this.listSubscription= this.myService.getSchedulingObserver();

    this.listSubscription.subscribe(lists=> {

      this.dataModel = lists;

      console.log("LISTS")
      console.log(lists)
      console.log("DATAMODEL")
      console.log(this.dataModel)
    });
```

With the console.log, the result is the following:

```
    LISTS
(2) ["{"name":"testing","desc":"test","other":"search"}", "{"name":"test","desc":"testing","other":"search"}"]
DATAMODEL
(2) ["{"name":"testing","desc":"test","other":"search"}", "{"name":"test","desc":"testing","other":"search"}"]
```

Finally in the html code, I am trying to get the variable using an NgFor, but not value is painted and there is no errors in the console. However data variable (first field)  is properly painted with the following format in the website and iterates twice over the ngFor:

```
{"name":"testing","desc":"test","other":"search"}
```

I think there is some kind of problem with the format of the array/json which I am not realizing.

```
<mat-card>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let data of dataModel">
      {{ data }}
      <p>DATA SLICED</p>
      {{ data.name}}
      {{ data.desc}}
      {{ data.other}}
      <p>END</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</mat-card>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the API returns the data as string it needs to be converted to JSON format.

```
this.dataModel.forEach((data, i) => {
  this.dataModel[i] = JSON.parse(data);
})

...................................

<mat-card>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let data of dataModel">
      {{ data|json }}
      <p>DATA SLICED</p>
      {{ data.name}}
      {{ data.desc}}
      {{ data.other}}
      <p>END</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: The solution is valid, however you cannot parse data when it is not an string. therefore I had to remove the assignment of dataModel to myModel and then it works properly. Thanks for the help